# c++ variadic template causing std::tuple error c2661

Tags: c++, templates, pointers, variadic

Writing this creates a compile error, how can i fix this ?

```
ThreadManager<MyWidget> u(&MyWidget::ss, this, false);
u.Invoke();
```

Severity    Code    Description Project File    Line    Suppression State
Error   C2661   '`std::tuple<void (__cdecl MyWidget::* )(void),MyWidget>::tuple`': no overloaded function takes 2 arguments

But this compiles fine

```
ThreadManager<MyWidget> u(&MyWidget::ss, this, false);
//u.Invoke();
```

Here is the code

```
#pragma once
#include <thread>

class __declspec(dllexport) ThreadBase
{};

template<class T, class... ARG>
class __declspec(dllexport) ThreadManager : public ThreadBase
{
    typedef void(T::*_func)(ARG...);

    std::thread m_thread;

    _func m_Func;
    const bool arged;
    T* m_Obj;

public:

    ThreadManager(_func f, T* obj, bool arged);

    void Invoke(ARG&&... args);

    ~ThreadManager();
};


template<class T,class... ARG>
void  ThreadManager<T, ARG...>::Invoke(ARG&&... args)
{
    if (!arged)
        m_thread = std::thread(m_Func, *m_Obj);
    else
        m_thread = std::thread(m_Func, *m_Obj, std::forward<ARG>(args)...);

    m_thread.detach();
}

template<class T,class... ARG>
ThreadManager<T,ARG...>::ThreadManager(_func f, T* obj, bool arged) : arged(arged), m_Obj(obj), m_Func(f)
{}


template<class T,class... ARG>
ThreadManager<T,ARG...>::~ThreadManager()
{
    m_thread.join();
}
```

Comment: Which compiler do you use? The code snippet you provided compiled OK on VS2015. Looks like the problem is not in code presented.

Comment: Please minimize your example and give compiler details; [mcve]